# Oracle: Call a function from "select from dual" do nothing

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have a function that inserts to and updates tables. Calling it from:

```
select AGENTS_REGISTRATION() from dual;
```

or:

```
declare
  x NUMBER;
begin
  select AGENTS_REGISTRATION() into x from dual;
end;
/
```

do nothing. Another form makes necessary changes:

```
declare
  x NUMBER;
begin
  x := AGENTS_REGISTRATION();
end;
/
```

What is wrong with first two expression?

Comment: What do you mean by 'do nothing'? Since DML is not allowed in a query you should have gotten ORA-14551 error.

Comment: I execute expressions in Oracle SQL Developer, but don't get ORA-14551. I see that people wrote *You can't use a function that modifies data in a **select** statement*. Can you add your comment as an answer? Didn't know that....

Comment: It's not allowed to perform DML operations inside a function. If as you put it "it does nothing", then there probably is `when others then null` or some other sort of exception handling construct that suppresses `ORA-14551` error.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov You are right, it has: `EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN` and error reporting inside EXCEPTION block also tries to write to DB, so I didn't have any sign of problem ((

Comment: what is **AGENTS_REGISTRATION** show its inside

Comment: Which is why you should never use WHEN OTHERS... unless you know exactly what you are doing and what are the consequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not allow `DML` operations inside a query. Calling function that `inserts/updates/deletes` data in a query will raise:

> ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query

Query will not raise error if `exception` was trapped inside the function - it is very dangerous to use `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler (or catching `ORA-14551` directly using `pragma exception_init`) without re-raising the error, as you have seen in this example.

Although I do not recommend this, it is possible to use `DML` operations in a query if function is defined as `autonomous transaction` (by using `pragma autonomous_transaction`) - but this WILL lead to more problems.

The solution is not to call function inside a query - it certainly does not make sense to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_14551_cannot_perform_a_dml_operation_inside_a_query.htm

```
create or replace function myFunction return varchar2 as
begin
update emp set empno = empno +1 where empno = 0;
return 'Yeah';
end; 
/


SQL> var myVar VARCHAR2
SQL> call myFunction() INTO :myVar;
SQL> print myVar
```